# switch to split screen in IntelliJ (ideaVim)

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

In Vim I can **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>** to switch to the split screen, how could one achieve the same in **IntelliJ**?

Example:

I press **:vsplit** it opens up a split-screen, now I'd like to switch between those screens.

I found this [changelog](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/src/com/maddyhome/idea/vim/package-info.java) but the option I'm looking for is not yet implemented.

Someone with another solution for this?

update:

I bruteforced some key combinations and it does change the screen when I press: **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>/<kbd>j</kbd>/<kbd>k</kbd>/<kbd>l</kbd> to navigate splits as in the original Vim. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> should work. If it doesn't for you, check File | Settings | Vim Emulation and your ~/.ideavimrc config for some keyboard shortcut clashes.

There is one known issue when one split has a row of open tabs that is higher than the row of another split, then you cannot switch to it due to the miscalculation in the window coordinates.

Comment: Additionally the control key bindings mentioned at http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Switch_between_Vim_window_splits_easily also work, so you can define things like `map <C-H> <C-W>h` for faster switching.

Comment: Warning: You need to use lower case h: `map <C-H> <C-W>h` works, but `map <C-H> <C-W>H` or `map <C-H> <C-W><C-H>` do _not_.

Comment: For some reason I can get h/j/k to work but not l (ie L) for moving to the right.

Comment: Update: I found a long-forgotten `<c-l>` remap hiding in the depths of my vimrc. Apparently the plugin I'd been using for vim/tmux navigation had already overridden it.

Comment: AHA! it was the double row of tabs thing that was throwing me off. Ctrl-w/l would work, but then Ctrl-w/h wouldn't. However, if I close the second row of tabes in the left window, it's fixed. That's annoying.

Answer (score 29):

`Ctrl` + `ww`  is a quick way to switch between windows. (Works for me on linux/intelliJ)

Comment: This is great because it bypasses the issue mentioned by Andrey

Comment: What did you do to get this to work? This does not work for me in Rider version 2022.2.3. I unmapped Ctrl + w from Extend Selection but still no luck.

Comment: @CoryKoch what os you on - When I answered this, I was on linux - Using a mac at the moment -- and it still works

Comment: @MzA I was on Windows 10

Comment: This works great on Macos + Goland in Vim mode

Answer (score 5):

So far only way I could get this to work was to add this to my .ideavimrc:

```
    sethandler <c-h> a:vim
    sethandler <c-l> a:vim
    sethandler <c-j> a:vim
    sethandler <c-k> a:vim
    nnoremap <c-h> <c-w>h
    nnoremap <c-l> <c-w>l
    nnoremap <c-j> <c-w>j
    nnoremap <c-k> <c-w>k
```

This is for IdeaVim version 1.11.1 on Windows 10